Scheduled Messages Command Processing Issue in Laravel 11
I'm facing an issue with a Laravel console command designed to send scheduled messages, and I would appreciate any help or insights from the community.
Problem Description
I've implemented a command that retrieves scheduled messages from the database and dispatches a job to send each message. While the first message is processed correctly, subsequent messages seem to use the previous iteration's values, leading to incorrect message dispatching.
Command Code
Here's the code for the command:
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Jobs\SendScheduledMessageJob;
use App\Models\ScheduledMessage;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;


class SendScheduledMessages extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'app:send-scheduled-messages';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send scheduled messages';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $messages = ScheduledMessage::where('scheduled_at', '<=', now())
            ->where('is_sent', false)
            ->get();

        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            SendScheduledMessageJob::dispatch($message);
        }
    }
}


and here is my console route for scheduling the task
<?php

use App\Models\ScheduledMessage;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Artisan::command('inspire', function () {
    $this->comment(Inspiring::quote());
})->purpose('Display an inspiring quote')->hourly();

Schedule::command('app:send-scheduled-messages')->everySecond()->description('Send scheduled messages');


and here is SendScheduledMessageJob
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\ScheduledMessage;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class SendScheduledMessageJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $message;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(ScheduledMessage $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        Log::info($this->message->scheduled_at);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {

        DB::transaction(function () {
            try {

                // Retrieve the messageable entity (the recipient)
                $messageable = $this->message->messageable;

                // Create a new message for the recipient with the content and sender ID
                $newMessage = $messageable->messages()->create([
                    'content' => $this->message->content,
                    'sender_id' => $this->message->sender_id,
                ]);

                // Check if the original message has attachments
                if ($this->message->attachments->isNotEmpty()) {
                    // Iterate through each attachment
                    foreach ($this->message->attachments as $attachment) {
                        // Generate a new path for the attachment, replacing the old message ID with the new one
                        $path = str_replace($this->message->id, $newMessage->id, $attachment->path);

                        // Determine the directory to remove after moving the file, up to "/attachments"
                        $path_to_remove = substr($attachment->path, 0, strpos($attachment->path, "/attachments"));

                        // Move the attachment to the new path
                        Storage::disk('public')->move($attachment->path, $path);

                        // Create a record for the attachment under the new message quietly (without raising events)
                        $newMessage->attachments()->createQuietly([
                            'path' => $path,
                            'name' => $attachment->name,
                        ]);

                        // Delete the old directory where the attachment was stored
                        Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory($path_to_remove);
                    }
                }

                // Mark the original message as sent
                $this->message->update(['is_sent' => true]);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // Log any exceptions
                Log::error('Failed to send message ID: ' . $this->message->id . ', Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}


these are scheduled messages which were added to database with following scheduled_at values

2024-07-03 12:14:00
2024-07-03 12:15:00
2024-07-03 12:16:00
2024-07-03 12:17:00

and these are logs which were generated
[2024-07-03 14:08:00] local.INFO: 2024-07-03 12:14:00
[2024-07-03 14:08:00] local.INFO: 2024-07-03 12:14:00
[2024-07-03 14:08:00] local.INFO: 2024-07-03 12:15:00
[2024-07-03 14:08:00] local.INFO: 2024-07-03 12:16:00


I need to confirm one thing. Tell me does the all records getting updated with 'is_sent' => true or it is only that 1st record that updated with  'is_sent' => true?

@Subha all of it
